# Loops within Switch statement

Tags: php, loops, breakpoints

my switch statement has about ten outcome, but some of them need 1/2 loops to check, so i can't write them within case(condition), so i've tried using more than one default case, is this possible?

```
<?php

switch(true) {
case 1:
    break;
case 2:
    break;
default:
    echo "this text is never printed ??";

    while(true) {
        while(true) { // case 3
            break 3;
        }

        break;
    }

    while(true) {
        // case 4
        break 2;
    }
case 5:
    break;
default:
    while(true) {
        // case 6
        break 2;
    }
case 7:
    break;
}

?>
```

is this sort of thing possible, as my first default doesn't seem to be executing at all?!

thanks

Comment: Apart from your question, this is most definitely a fine example for the merits of use of good ol' encapsulation.

Comment: okay thanks guys. i've done what you have said and put all these "special cases" in a deault case at the end, which means i've had to order my code differently :(

i'd quite like a special class which you can put anywhere in the structure, and the correct number of breaks is called, then the switch ends, otherwise, check the rest of the cases. this would stop the work arounds in the default case!

Franz: i'm writing a function that looks at pokers cards and analyses what hand you have. so case 1 would have been royal flush, and i wanted to keep it in order and stop after it finds the best hand

Comment: Those who are saying you can have only one default are incorrect; it is true that only the last one would be executed. And those who say that evaluation stops when the default case is reached are also incorrect. These are easy to test, if anyone is so inclined.

Comment: @Judding - In your example code the default isn't executed because true == 1. Put some echo statements in your cases to see what's happening (or not, and keep on guessing).

Comment: @GZipp: Whether or not the PHP parser is willing to interpret multiple `default` s doesn't change the fact that it makes zero logical sense to have more than one. Multiple `default` s is *WRONG* no matter what the PHP parser/runtime allow. You do however, make a good point about `switch(true)` always leading to `case 1:` which I overlooked initially. `switch(true)` should almost certainly be changed to `switch($someVariable)` where `$someVariable` contains a value corresponding to one of the `case` s. With that modification, most of the answers below hold true.

Comment: @GZipp: As for `default` being last, this is a (good) convention across practically all languages that support the `switch` construct and should be followed in PHP for readability/maintainability.

Comment: @Asaph - I did not say that having more than one default is not a bad thing. Nor did I say that the default should be anywhere but last. I pointed out that two things said multiple times in the answers were incorrect; to me, incorrect information does not "hold true."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have more than one `default` in a switch statement. Also, `default` should be at the end of of the `switch` after all the `case` statements.

What *might* be happening when your code is run through the PHP engine is that the parser is reading the switch statements into a hash map type data structure and each time the parser finds a `default` label, it's overwriting the existing entry in the hash map. So only last `default` label ends up in the data structure that gets used in execution.

Answer (score 3):

No this isn't possible, you can't have more than one default case in a switch statement, you'll need to put additional logic into the single final case statement.

when the default case is reached it captures all conditions so later cases are not evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question - no, it is only possible to have one default and that at the end. I'm not sure whether you can place other cases after the default, but what I'm sure of is that they would never be reached...

**EDIT**:
Also, I don't see what you're trying to do there. What's the point? Could you explain a bit? We might be able to help you accomplish what you want to do

Comment: As Baxter writes, if you need to do some special checking for some of the cases, just leave them out and do the checks in the `default` section.

Answer (score 1):

You can have only one default in a switch. Remember that Zend is *not* the only thing that parses PHP, you may confuse other parsers by not putting the default case as the very last part of the switch.